# Why is fileinput.input object not lost when going out-of-scope?

Tags: python, scope

In the following code I would expect than python is freeing `fileinput.input` when I'm `return`ing in the middle my loop as it is going out-of-scope. However, when calling again my function fileinput tells me

```
raise RuntimeError, "input() already active"
```

Here is my code:

```
def func(inplace):
    for line in fileinput.input(sys.argv[1], inplace=inplace):
        [..]
        if condition:
             return True
        [..]

if func(False):
    func(True)
```

I would expect this behavior when using `yield` but not when using return.

I'm using Python 2.7.3.

Is there any way to force a reset of fileinput?

**EDIT**:

When calling `fileinput.close()` before returning it works. Why is it not done implicitly?

**EDIT 2**: Thanks to @MatsLindh

Replacing

```
for line in fileinput.input(sys.argv[1], inplace=inplace):
```

with

```
for line in fileinput.FileInput(sys.argv[1], inplace=inplace):
```

does what I want, because it returns an object which goes out-of-scope in a defined manner. I assumed that `fileinput.input()` does that, but no. It is using a global instance.

Comment: Why would you expect this? Python does not guarantee cleanup on block end (it's just cpython that usually does this but only when there are not reference cycles).

Comment: Garbage collection can occur any time; and there are conditions around when objects are freed adn cleaned up. If you want the file object to be closed when you exit the block use ``with``

Comment: @JamesMills I think you should make your comment an answer. It seems to be that, IMHO.

Comment: Garbage collection should not (and does not, I strongly hope, even with python) interfere with cleanup of objects which are going out-of-scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing here that can go out of scope - you're calling a function in a module that has been imported, and `fileinput` is one of those modules that has global state, since future calls to `fileinput` maps to the previously made `input` call.

You should be able to work around this by using the `FileInput` class instead, which will be recreated the next time you call `func()` and by using `with` together with that object.

Or - as you discovered, calling `close()` which resets the internal module state.

Comment: I think you're nailing it. My assumption was that fileinput.input() returns an object. Which goes out of scope when leaving the loop.

Answer (score 4):

So you *need* to wrap `fileinput.input()` in a `closing` "context manager" which will **ensure*8 that `.close()` is called when you exit the block by using `with ...:`:

```
from contextlib import closing

def func(inplace):
    with closing(fileinput.input(sys.argv[1], inplace=inplace)) as finput:
        for line in finput: 
            [..]
            if condition:
                return True
            [..]
```

Using a context manager on objects that implement the protocol; usually file objects and the like you **ensure** that cleaned operations are performed on exit of the `with` block.

---

> Garbage collection can occur any time; and there are conditions around when 
>   objects are freed adn cleaned up. If you want the file object to be closed when you exit the block use `with`.

Comment: `fileinput` is a [standard python module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) that keeps global state about the previous call to `input()` for future calls to other fileinput functions.

Comment: Yeah; exactly; The **key** thing here is to use a "context manager".

Comment: `FileInput` (what's returned from `input()`) doesn't implement `__exit__()`, hence the need for `closing()`

Comment: I accepted Mats' answer. We should not mix up garbage collection and an object's scope. My misunderstanding what that fileinput is a global 'object' which keeps its state between function-calls because its scope is global. My conclusion: one should not use fileinput, but always `fileinput.FileInput()`

Comment: Yeah that's *fair enough*. I'm ignorant of ``fileinput`` myself; but global state is *hard* to debug and you *should* use ``with`` and "context managers" when you expect/want file-like objects to close on the end of a scoped block of code.

Answer (score 2):

> When calling fileinput.close() before returning it works. Why is it not done implicitly?

[Because](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): *Explicit is better than implicit.*

Python does not in any way guarantee block cleanup semantics, i.e. a resource is not necessarily cleaned up immediately when it goes out of scope. The CPython implementation uses conservative reference counting so that it may seem that this is the case. It isn't. That's why there's *also* cyclic garbage collection.

If you want cleanup, do it explicitly:

```
from contextlib import closing

def func(inplace):
    with closing(fileinput.input(sys.argv[1], inplace=inplace)) as finput:
        for line in finput:
            [..]
        if condition:
             return True
        [..]
```

The `closing()` wrapper is needed because `FileInput` objects --at least on python 2.7-- are not context managers, i.e. there's no `__exit__()` method.

Comment: I'd like to extend your phrase: *Python does not in any way guarantee block cleanup semantics* with *except if you are using it correctly.*

Answer (score 2):

File-like objects aren't implicitly closed. Also, `FileInput` doesn't support the `with` statement.

However, you can use the [`closing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) context manager:

```
from contextlib import closing

with closing(fileinput.input(inplace=inplace)) as input:
    for line in input:
        if condition:
            return True
```

I removed the `files=sys.argv[1]` argument for brevity and as the default is `sys.argv[1:]`. I assume this will still do what you want.